# Replace formula with its result in javascript

Tags: javascript

What's the equivalent function for `range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly:True})` in JavaScript. I'm trying to replace formula with its result in javascript

Comment: where do you get `copyTo` from?

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm guessing it's from another programming language.

Comment: @NinaScholz It's from VB

Comment: please add what it does.

Comment: Loop your object and put only values to new array

Answer (score 0):

There's the eval function in javaScript.
What it does is evaluating a string.

Example:

```
eval('3 + 2')
5
```

In your case it may look something like this:

```
arrayOfResults = arrayOfStrings.map( (formula) => eval(formula));
```

Comment: I don't require the eval function here since the formula already gives me the desired result in google sheet. What i'm trying to do here is to remove the formula of cell and paste as values(content of the cell). So, I'm looking for a function that does that